# In which format the data is stored in Wordpress Databases?

Tags: database, options

In lot of cases, I have seen the wordpress stores data in JSON like structure but not exactly JSON.

For example, in usermeta table, this is the value (with meta key as wpkgbe_capabilities)
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}

it seems as a JSON data structure but not exactly a JSON data structure.
How do we decode this structure and what is it called?

Comment: If you'd like to see this data from the options table in a more user-friendly format, I found this command using the WP CLI helpful: `wp option list --search="<row_name>" --format=yaml --unserialize`

Answer (score 3):

That's not JSON, it's serialised PHP data. If you try to store a value that isn't a primitive string/number, such as an object or array, WordPress serializes it using PHP.

> How do we decode this structure

```php
deserialize( ... );
```

**However, I do not recommend relying on this for practical and security reasons. Don't store structured data as strings in the database, and if you must do it, use JSON or CSV.**

For data WP stores, you don't deserialize the data, but rather you call the relevant WordPress/plugin API and let WordPress/plugins handle it. Accessing WP data using direct database calls and bypassing the PHP based APIs is a common beginner mistake.

### Security and Backwards Compatibility

Because passing complex data will get it serialized and deserialized transparently into PHP for ease of use, switching away to a standard format with fewer risks such as JSON is not a trivial task.

This is made worse by security issues, namely object deserialisation attacks. PHP will recreate objects when they're deserialised, running their constructors, and opening a potential attack vector.

There's also the corruption problem when a user naively performs an `UPDATE` sql query to change text values, such as search replacing a URL. This is because the serialized data structure contains the length of the value, so if the value changes length but the number is not updated then the structure is corrupted.